# Settings/Options Icon Hidden Issue

Tags: bug, developer-story, timeline

Today I was updating new items in my Developer Story Timeline and ran into weird issue.

I was adding a new item as shown below and it worked well. It was added to my timeline.

[image: Adding demo to Timeline]

After that I realized that I made a typo so I wanted to edit it, That was the time I got confused. The Setting(Options) icons was not there. I saw other posts, I was able to see that icon on them. Follow the screenshot below.

I tried editing the other posts and again options icon was getting hidden.

[image: Settings icon hidden]

I had to refresh the whole page in order to get options icon back on the cards.

**This issue exists when you add or edit any cards into timeline.**

Is this issue known or is it intentional?

[image: Settings icon available after refresh]

Client Details :

Browser : **Google Chrome**

Version : **77.0.3865.90 (Official Build) (64-bit)**

OS : **Windows 10**

Zoom size : **100% (Default)**